# Multiple connections under a barrier terminal strip screw

Tags: wire-terminals, crimp, screw-terminal

Multiple connections under a barrier terminal strip screw.

I know that you shouldn't place two wires under the screw of a breaker, called "double lugging" and can make for a bad connection and dangerous.   But when using a terminal barrier and crimp on 'U' or fork connectors, can I place more than one connection under each screw ?

Thanks

Comment: The problem with 'double lugging' is that , over time as the connection heats up and cools off, the screw can get loose.  I presume mainly because the wires are actually round, hard to get alotta surface area on them.   But in a terminal strip where you've got 'fork' connectors???  I don't see it as a problem.  I'd suggest ring-eyes though, so even if something gets loose, it doesn't fall off completely.  You can also get ring-eyes with built-in 'lock nut' fingers  ala  https://www.te.com/content/dam/te-com/catalog/part/000/617/944/61794-4-t1.jpg/jcr:content/renditions/product-details.png

Comment: Could you use one breaker per wire? Or a screw terminal bus bar?

Comment: Its not in an electrical box, just a barrier strip to provide AC to some lights.  
Just wanted to know the communities thoughts on multiple terminations under one screw terminal.\

Comment: If using Eurostyle Terminal Strip you could crimp two wires together using a ferrule before screwing to terminal